# awk one liner select only rows based on value of a column

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I'd like to read **filein.txt** (tab delimited) and output a **fileout.txt** with only rows that match the value of a given column, and eliminate the column being queried. i.e.,

```
filein.txt
#name\thouse\taddress
roger\tvictorian\t223 dolan st.
maggie\tfrench\t12 alameda ave.
kingston\tvictorian\t224 house st.
robert\tamerican\t22 dolan st.
```

Let us say I'd like to select only the rows where the houses are of `victorian` style, then my **fileout.txt** should look like:

```
fileout.txt
#name\taddress
roger\t223 dolan st.
kingston\t224 house st.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
awk -F"\t" '$2 == "victorian" { print $1"\t"$3 }' file.in
```

Comment: +1. Instead of hardcoding the tab in the print statement, you could also write `print $1 FS $3`. Matter of preference only.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with the following `awk` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

style="victorian"
awk -v s_style=$style 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
    $2==s_style {$2=""; sub("\t\t","\t"); print}'
```

**Explanation:**

- `style="victorian"`: assign the house style that you want to select outside of the `awk` script so it's easier to maintain
- `awk`: invoke awk
- `-v s_style=$style`: the `-v` option passes an external variable into awk. Need to specify this for each variable you pass in. In this case it assigns the external variable `$style` to the awk variable `s_style`.
- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}`: tells awk that the field separators in the output should be tabs, not spaces by default.
- `{$2==s_style {$2=""; sub("\t\t","\t"); print}}'`: If the 2nd field is the house type specified in `s_style` (in this case, `victorian`), then remove it and print the line.

**Alternatively**, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

style="victorian"
awk -v s_style=$style 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
    $2==s_style {print $1, $3}'
```

but this assumes that your input files will not have additional fields separated by tabs in the future.

Comment: +1. Simply as a matter of style, I'd defing FS with OFS in the BEGIN block and remove the if statement: `awk -v s=$style 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} $2 == s {print $1, $3}'`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks =) I'm still new to shell scripts; edited my answer to reflect your comments

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors in your last edit. With awk, the body consists of CONDITION {ACTION} pairs, where the ACTION body is only executed if the CONDITION returns true. The BEGIN block is only true before the first input line is read, and we only want to print when the condition "$2 == s" returns true.

Comment: I'd drop the BEGIN block completely: `awk '$2==s{print $1, $3}' s=$style OFS=\\t FS=\\t`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm still new to `awk`, would you mind pointing me to some resources that could help me compare the differences between these 2 approaches?

Comment: There's no difference, just stylistic preference.  `-v` strikes me as an unnecessary option, and I don't like `BEGIN` blocks for initializing variables, except in a script.

Answer (score 2):

Using the OFS (Output Field Separator) variable, you can avoid hard coding between rows:

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '$2 == "victorian" { print $1,$3 }' file.in
```